# Extract the product names, quantities and unit prices and place them into a data frame containing the items in each order

Tags: r, dataframe

I have this data frame, from a file rds.
I extract these variables and create a data frame call items

```
items <- unique ((orders[,c("Order_ID","Quantities","Products","Prices")]))
items %>% as.data.frame()
```

The result is this :

```
     Order_ID Quantities                                          Products              Prices
1       69          2                                  Meatlovers Pizza               13.99
2     3025       1, 1                  Supreme Pizza, BBQ Chicken Pizza        13.95, 14.95
3     3549       3, 3                   Seafood Pizza, Vegetarian Pizza        13.99, 10.99
4       27    2, 2, 3 Margherita Pizza, Supreme Pizza, Meatlovers Pizza 10.99, 13.95, 13.99
```

I need to Extract the product names, quantities and unit prices and place them into a data frame containing the items in each order (i.e. one row for every item in order). The order that a row in this data frame is associated with should be identifiable by the order ID.
How can I do it?

The final data frame looks like :

```
     Order_ID           Products Prices Quantities
1       69   Meatlovers Pizza  13.99          2
2     3025      Supreme Pizza  13.95          1
3     3025  BBQ Chicken Pizza  14.95          1
4     3549      Seafood Pizza  13.99          3
5     3549   Vegetarian Pizza  10.99          3
6       27   Margherita Pizza  10.99          2
7       27      Supreme Pizza  13.95          2
8       27   Meatlovers Pizza  13.99          3
```

Please help!!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hi there, how can operate this columns in this particular data frame using a function;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64410046/hi-there-how-can-operate-this-columns-in-this-particular-data-frame-using-a-fun)

Comment: Please add your data using `dput`. Read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).  Have you tried answers from this post?

Comment: Yes, we try but is not working.